# Incompatible Axis 1 client with Axis 2 Web Service

Tags: java, eclipse, soap, axis

I have an Axis 1 web service with an Axis 1 client. Everything is working quite well, and the data I'm getting from the web service is correct. Now, there's a requirement to move the web service to use Axis 2, I'm having problems to get data on the Axis 1 client. I have used SOAPUI to see the format of the response that I'm getting.

With the Axis 1 web service, the response was as follows:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <getInventoryResponse xmlns="http://webservices.com">
         <getInventory>
            <errorCode>10071</errorCode>
            <inventory xsi:nil="true"/>
         </getLastInventoryCountReturn>
      </getInventoryResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

With the Axis 2 web service, the response is as follows:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:getInventoryResponse xmlns:ns="http://webservices.com">
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax21:Inventory" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ax21="http://model.com/xsd">
            <ax21:errorCode>10071</ax21:errorCode>
            <ax21:inventory xsi:nil="true"/>
         </ns:return>
      </ns:getInventoryResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

As you can see, the element called "errorCode" has a value of 10071. I'm receiving the errorCode value correctly on the client from both web services. But I have a complex type called "Inventory" that I receive as part of the response (It doesn't appear in the responses I have included above 'cause it will take me some time to populate the appropriate data on the web service). The InventoryItem contains fields of different data types (String, Calendar). What I have noticed is that the response from the Axis 2 web service contains the `<axs21>` xml tag whereas in the Axis 1 web service, it's not there. So I'm assuming that I have a parsing problem on the client side with the response coming from the Axis 2 web service.

Does anyone know how can I solve this?

Comment: What are the incompatibilities you see with the Axis2 generated wsdl? Axis2 generates doc/lit type wsdl by default. This should work with any soap frame work.

Comment: I have edited my post to better describe the problem. Please check it and let me know what do you think.

Comment: What do you mean with I **assume** I have a problem? It seems likely that it will be a problem, but you haven't tested?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I think if you understand the essence what he wants to say, and you then fix his question, I think it would be considered as a big honor and practically never as a destructive deed. Actually, you help him with your language skill, which is trivial to you, but very hard for him.  If somebody formulates unclear English with alien structures, it is not because he has alien thoughts. He has the same thought as the native speakers, only he is unable to perfectly communicate them. (Btw, if he is unsatisfied with your change, he is always ready to not accept the change or revert it.)

Comment: I've just read the answer here, which is simply to regenerate the client using Axis 2. I guess we either have to reopen this question *or*, IMHO more useful, close it because this action is quite the logical thing to do when upgrading to Axis 2 in general. I mean, that's not really an answer to making Axis 1 client compatible with Axis 2 as asked.

Comment: This question was asked four years ago back when I was still new to the concept of web services and web service clients. I've come a long way since then. The reason why I chose to close it is because with its current structure/problem, I utterly believe that it won't help anyone solve anything.

@peterh Not being able to clearly explain what the problem is doesn't necessarily mean that I don't have a good command of the language. It could also mean that back then, I didn't understand the problem myself.

Comment: @MouhammedSoueidane Despite that the answer could be useful for the googlers of the future, I would suggest to vote for reopen after it was closed (unfortunately, there is 4 VtCs already).

Comment: @peterh If you want to create a self answered Q/A that basically says: if you want to upgrade to Axis 2 then you have to upgrade the client as well, please do so. I'd even upvote it if you link to it from here. I agree though with Mouhammed that this rather extensive question won't help too many people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently I was doing something wrong. I had to **recreate my client code** when moving the web service from Axis 1 to Axis2.